# Using custom location of translate file with ng2 translate

Tags: angular

I created Angular2 app and using ng2 translate package for translation.
I'm using the static loader to load my translated files(en.json).
I can't figure out how I can change the Path of the static loader to be relative to the URL of the site and not try and find the translate file under the root directory.
Should i create a new loader and load the files myself?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a custom loader to change the file path. But I haven't got around to fix the problem of not loading the translations which aren't present in the new file.